# gulp - using symlink in task source

Tags: gulp

i have the following problem: i'm running gulp and one of the task is

```
gulp.task("default", function() {
return gulp.src([
        "requirements.txt",
        "**/symfile"
        "!**/node_modules/**/*"])
    .pipe(tar('prebuilt.tar'))
    .pipe(gzip())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

the symfile is a symbol link created with `ln`

I get the following error :

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/dorb/symfile'`

I just want that in my tar file i will have a symlink without where he points - i will take care of it later, just want a symlink file in my tar file.

i tried and work with `vinyl-fs` but that just create symlink and i want to use a symlink a source for gulp task 'default' as explained.